# How to encode then decode a JSON in Swift to escape characters?

Tags: json, swift, postico

How to encode and then decode to JSON, to escape meantime the special character?

I have now this code:

```swift
let o5: [String: Any] = ..
let o6 = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: o5, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys
let o7 = try decoder.decode(Organization.self, from: o6)
```

I would do following text replacement: `/` -> `\/`, new line -> `\n`, `"` -> `\"`.

Recently I have unfortunatelly unescaped special characters in my DB.

[image]

Comment: What problem do these non-escaped characters cause? If it's a valid JSON, what do you need escaping for?

Comment: Forward slashes don't need escaping. E.g., `"https://tiket.hu/buyTicket?status=550825558922085"` is a fine string, as it is.

Comment: The challange if I export the DB into CSV and would load in again, Postico will not accept it, as JSON records are not valid records, as they have special unescaped characters. Basically I can not make a backup.

Comment: If you export the DB into CSV and try to load it again, the problem is either in your export/import of the CSV or your choice of CSV for import/export at all. But trying to manually edit the JSON to get around a faulty import/export process is not the right solution. The payload is what the payload is. Don't change that. Fix the import/export process. There isn't enough information in your question, yet, for us to help you, though.

Comment: I just tried exporting a table with forward slashes in Postico and it worked fine. (I also did it in TablePlus with CSV, JSON, and SQL formats, and those worked fine, too.) I think you're going to have to share more debugging details. But the forward slashes do not need escaping.

Comment: Maybe the `/` maybe the `"`. Did you use `/` is a JSON type record?